# Software for reducing motion-blur in videos

Tags: video, photography, video-editing

I'm familiar with software such as [SmartDeblur](http://smartdeblur.net/) and the like for removing motion blur, etc. from images. These typically work impressively well, however they are unable to handle *video* files.

I'm looking for similar software (*preferably* open-source) that is able to do the same for video files, can do so on CPU, and works on either/or Windows/Linux.